# how to divide the amount for each record on specific condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table let's assume X
and I want to join it to another table Y

this the content of X

```
ID    |  value 
------------------
100   | -500
200   | 45
300   | -100
```

table Y

```
ID   |  store_code
---------------------
100  | 7001
100  | 7002
100  | 7003
200  | 3001
200  | 3002
300  | 5001
```

If I made a relationship between X & Y tables
the amount it will be duplicated, so if I used sum function the total will be wrong

I decided to divide the amount between the stores for each ID
for example
the amount for ID 200 will be like this

```
ID | store_code | amount
200 | 3001 | 22.5
200 | 3002 | 22.5
```

when I use sum function the result will return to its original value 45

how can I do this calculation in SQL code?

Comment: when you say amount , what do you mean ?? there is no explanation in your question how do you calculate that value based on the join condition x.id = y.id . Is it the column value ?

Comment: Is X really a table or is it just aggregated inner view?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov it is a table

Comment: @RobertoHernandez , I did a mistake when I typed the name all of them are value. to be more clarified amount = value in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If I understand correctly, you want to allocate the full value over multiple rows.  Use window functions:

```
select y.id, y.store_code,
       (x.value / count(*) over (partition by y.id)) as amount
from x join
     y
     on x.id = y.id
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess this the best way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select id, store_code, value/count amount
from(select x.id, y.store_code, y.value, 
     count(x.id) OVER (PARTITION BY store_code) count 
     from x JOIN y ON x.id = y.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to aggregate that?
If yes, you can just add X.value into group-by list and select-list as-is.

Comment: I do not want to aggregate it, on the contrary. I need to separate the value between the store codes